# Boxing the big equations ( generated by \dmath )

Tags: equations, longtable, boxes, ieee-style, boldmath

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath}
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Pi}{\mathrm{d} u}=A E \int_{0}^{L} \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} x} \frac{\mathrm{~d}(\delta u)}{\mathrm{~d} x}\mathrm{~d} x -\int_{0}^{L} q \delta u \mathrm{~d} x =0  \label{10}
\end{dmath}
\end{document}
```

[image]

but

I expect the equation to come inside a box
[image]

my code uses dmath as equation is big,   I use in IEEE class actually, so help me for boxing the big equations

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}

\begin{dmath}[frame, framesep={1em}]
\frac{\mathrm{d} \Pi}{\mathrm{d} u}=A E \int_{0}^{L} \frac{\mathrm{d} u}{\mathrm{~d} x} \frac{\mathrm{~d}(\delta u)}{\mathrm{~d} x}\mathrm{~d} x -\int_{0}^{L} q \delta u \mathrm{~d} x =0 \label{10}
\end{dmath}

\end{document}
```

[image]